# SQL - inner join (where,and,not)

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I have 2 tables:

```
1) STUDENTS-> primery key- id (int)
                     - firstName
                     - lastName
                     - city
2) GRADES->   primery key- studentID (int)
              primery key- courseID ('e' or 'h' or 'm')
                     - grade
```

Im trying to select student names that took the course 'm' and didnt took the course 'h' or 'e'.

my solution is:

```
SELECT  * FROM STUDENTS S
INNER JOIN GRADES G1 ON S.ID=G1.STUDENTID
INNER JOIN GRADES G2 ON G1.COURSEID !=G2.COURSEID AND G1.STUDENTID = G1.STUDENTID
WHERE (G1.COURSEID = 'Math ' AND NOT  (G2.COURSEID = 'Eng  ' OR G2.COURSEID = 'Heb'))
```

any idea what is wrong?

Comment: You should make StudentID at GRADES table, as Foreign Key

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM STUDENTS S 
INNER JOIN GRADES G ON S.ID=G.STUDENTID and G.COURSEID = 'Math '
where s.id not in (
  select STUDENTID from GRADES where COURSEID = 'Eng ' OR G2.COURSEID = 'Heb'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using Left Join

```
SELECT G1.STUDENTID, G1.firstName, G1.COURSEID!
FROM GRADES G1
LEFT JOIN STUDENTS S ON S.ID=G1.STUDENTID
GROUP BY G1.STUDENTID
HAVING G1.COURSEID='Math' AND G1.COURSEID!='Heb' AND G1.COURSEID!='Eng'
```

Also, you should keep, StudentId at GRADES table as Foreign Key

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT a.firstName, a.lastName, b.courseID
FROM STUDENTS a
INNER JOIN GRADES b
ON a.id = b.studentID
AND b.courseID = 'Math'
WHERE a.id NOT IN (
SELECT studentID FROM GRADES b 
WHERE courseID = 'Eng'
OR b.courseID = 'heb')
```

use this

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it.

You can use `NOT EXISTS` or `GROUP BY ... HAVING` as follows:

```
-- 1

SELECT * FROM STUDENTS S
INNER JOIN GRADES G1 ON S.ID = G1.STUDENTID
WHERE G1.COURSEID = 'Math'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM GRADES G2
        WHERE G2.STUDENTID = G1.STUDENTID
          AND G2.COURSEID IN ('Eng','Heb')
    );

-- 2 

SELECT S.ID, S.FIRSTNAME, S.LASTNAME FROM STUDENTS S
       INNER JOIN GRADES G1 ON S.ID = G1.STUDENTID
       WHERE COURSEID IN ('Math','Eng','Heb')
GROUP BY S.ID, S.FIRSTNAME, S.LASTNAME
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN COURSEID IN ('Eng','Heb') THEN 1 END) = 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN COURSEID = 'Math' THEN 1 END) <> 0
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation :

```
select s.id
from student s inner join
     grades g
     on g.studentid = s.studentid
group by s.id
having sum(case when g.courseid in ('eng', 'hub') then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when g.courseid = 'Math' then 1 else 0 end) = 1;
```